# Joomla 4 session does not expire at front end

Tags: session, joomla, joomla4

Currently, I am working on Joomla 4 and integrating website with Joomla version 4.2.5.
From global config, I have set up session handler option to 'Database' and Session life time to 15 minutes.

At front end side, user does not logged out, if user stay ideal more than 15 minutes

Also, I have checked by installed Joomla 4.2.5 and test same functionality, session handler does not working with default Joomla as well.

Does anyone have an idea is this bug of Joomla 4.2.5 or do I need to update anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After check on internet and debugged code of Joomla version 4.2.5, I found that below piece of code from Joomla keep session active and due to that after session time user does not logged out at front end and remain login apart from session timeout period.

```
HTMLHelper::_('behavior.keepalive');
```